# ''Fault' is already defined [ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here" could you help me

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin

```
How can ı fix 
'Fault' is already defined
[ERROR] file:Services.wsdl [16541,13]: (related to above error) the first definition appears here
```

pom.xml cxf plugin:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or3q3.png

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the wsdl great but, with the little information I can say, that you have defined an Element/Method twice or you have an import which is not namespaced correctly and is pulling in the same definition.

Comment: this file  Fault twice :     <xs:element name="Fault" type="ns44:FaultType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
    Do not use in domain specific schema, provided for the sole purpose of
    generating examples.
   </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>

Comment: @user3053933 can you share the full WSDL?

Comment: you look  from link https://filebin.net/ys35ymtswh6efrwq

Comment: do you opened link

Comment: @user3053933 I'm looking at it now, I can open the link thank you

Comment: @user3053933 I assume you cannot share the other schema imports inside the wsdl.
That's ok.. Can  you open the import schemas to check for the usage of the word fault. 

Also I've seen instances where "Fault" gets keyed off as a reserve word even though it's not an official reserve word

Comment: becuase this file send another person.So ı dont know

Comment: ı try different plugin Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project demo: Error generating Java code from WSDL